# How to parse polygons from GML in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2

I'm reading a GML file from an URL. This file contains polygons. I would like to draw the polygons on a map, where each should have a different color. But all examples I found on the web so far seemed to be outdated and didn't work. Any Hints?

Here the parsing (that's the part that already works):

```js
    var theParser = new OpenLayers.Format.GML();
    theParser.internalProjection = null;
    theParser.externalProjection = null;
    theParser.extractStyles      = false;
    theParser.extractAttributes  = true;
    var features = theParser.read(response.responseText);
    if(features)
    {
         for(var i=0;i<features.length;i++)
        {
            var feature = features[i]
       //Each feature is an instance of OpenLayers.Feature.Vector
           //Each has an attribte geometry, which is of type 
           //OpenLayers.Geometry.MultiPolygon and which contains an
           //OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon
        }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically you need to specify the feature namespace or else OpenLayers cannot deserialize your GML. And use the appropriate version of GML Parser.

Here's a [working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/YrpEY/)

This is they important part:

```js
var gmlOptions = {
    featureType: "feature",
    featureNS: "http://example.com/feature"
};
var gmlOptionsIn = OpenLayers.Util.extend(
    OpenLayers.Util.extend({}, gmlOptions)
);

var format = new OpenLayers.Format.GML.v3(gmlOptionsIn);

var features = format.read(strGML);
```

I'm still working on changing colors for each feature. Will update when i figure that one out.

---

## **UPDATE #2: Give each feature a different color:**

Here's a way you can give them a different color:

[Updated Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/YrpEY/1/)

```js
var style = $.extend(true, {}, OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style['default']); // get a copy of the default style
style.fillColor = "${getFillColor}";

var getRandomColor = function () {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        color += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 15)];
    }
    return color;
};

var myStyleMap = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
    "default": new OpenLayers.Style(style, {
        context: {
            getFillColor: function (feature) {
                return getRandomColor();
            }
        }
    })
}); 

var gmlLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("MyGMLLayer", {
    styleMap: myStyleMap
});
```