# Adding all polygons in GML from MapServer to openlayers using WFS

Tags: polygon, openlayers, wfs, mapserver, gml

I want to show the contents from MapServer (returned as GML given below) as WFS layer in OpenLayers map (OpenLayers v5.0.0). The problem is that only one polygon is added to the map. Here is the code that I have used:

```
var projection = new ol.proj.Projection({
    code: 'EPSG:4326',
    units: 'm',
    global: true,
    axisOrientation: 'neu',
});
console.log(projection);
ol.proj.addProjection(projection);

var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        url: url,
        format: new ol.format.GML3({
            srsName: "EPSG:4326",
            featurePrefix: 'ms',
            featureType: "Region_Map",
            featureNS: "http://mapserver.gis.umn.edu/mapserver"
        }),
        projection: projection,
    })
});
console.log(vector);
map.addLayer(vector)
```

GML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<wfs:FeatureCollection
   xmlns:ms="http://mapserver.gis.umn.edu/mapserver"
   xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
   xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"
   xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://mapserver.gis.umn.edu/mapserver http://localhost/MapServer/mapserv.exe?map=c:/inetpub/wwwroot/data//Region_Map_01392779-38eb-4685-a94c-d738038843a6.map&amp;SERVICE=WFS&amp;VERSION=1.1.0&amp;REQUEST=DescribeFeatureType&amp;TYPENAME=Name&amp;OUTPUTFORMAT=text/xml;%20subtype=gml/3.1.1  http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd">
      <gml:boundedBy>
        <gml:Envelope srsName="EPSG:4326">
            <gml:lowerCorner>8.428503 77.171508</gml:lowerCorner>
            <gml:upperCorner>9.201230 77.398780</gml:upperCorner>
        </gml:Envelope>
      </gml:boundedBy>
    <gml:featureMember>
      <ms:Region_Map gml:id="Name.Layer.fid1">
        <gml:boundedBy>
            <gml:Envelope srsName="EPSG:4326">
                <gml:lowerCorner>8.428503 77.353326</gml:lowerCorner>
                <gml:upperCorner>8.473957 77.398780</gml:upperCorner>
            </gml:Envelope>
        </gml:boundedBy>
        <ms:msGeometry>
          <gml:Polygon srsName="EPSG:4326">
            <gml:exterior>
              <gml:LinearRing>
                <gml:posList srsDimension="2">8.428503 77.398780 8.428503 77.353326 8.473957 77.353326 8.473957 77.398780 8.428503 77.398780 </gml:posList>
              </gml:LinearRing>
            </gml:exterior>
          </gml:Polygon>
        </ms:msGeometry>
        <!--other content-->
      </ms:Region_Map>
    </gml:featureMember>
    <gml:featureMember>
      <ms:Region_Map gml:id="Name.Layer.fid2">
        <gml:boundedBy>
            <gml:Envelope srsName="EPSG:4326">
                <!--some coordinates similar to above-->
            </gml:Envelope>
        </gml:boundedBy>
        <ms:msGeometry>
          <gml:Polygon srsName="EPSG:4326">
            <gml:exterior>
              <gml:LinearRing>
                <gml:posList srsDimension="2">Similar to above</gml:posList>
              </gml:LinearRing>
            </gml:exterior>
          </gml:Polygon>
        </ms:msGeometry>
        <!-- other data-->
      </ms:Region_Map>
    </gml:featureMember>
    <!--Other such tags-->
</wfs:FeatureCollection>
```

Please tell me what is the error. I did try out a few other related answers like [this one on setting featureNS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75756/openlayers-and-wfs-using-a-mapfile-correctly-with-featuretype-and-featurens) and [this one on parsing polgons](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20315/how-to-parse-polygons-from-gml-in-openlayers) but haven't reached a satisfactory result. Pleas help.

**UPDATE**

Based on the answer by ThomasG77 I tried the following two attempts (also referred to the OpenLayers API)

*Attempt 1* - Simply replaced the `ol.format.GML3({...})` with `ol.format.WFS({...})` in above code leaving all else the same.

*Attempt 2* - Used this code instead of the code written in `ol.format.GML3({...})`

```
format: new ol.format.WFS({
    featureType: "Region_Map",
    featureNS: "http://mapserver.gis.umn.edu/mapserver",
    gmlFormat: new ol.format.GML3({
        srsName: "EPSG:4326",
        surface: true,
        multiSurface: true
    })
}),
```

In both cases, I ended up seeing no polygons added to the map. I even referred to the answers linked by @ThomasG77.

Is there some other issue with my code too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `ol.format.WFS` instead of `ol.format.GML3`. I have made numerous answers related to your issue e.g [Add GML Layer in OpenLayers 4](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/267476/add-gml-layer-in-openlayers-4),  [WFS not working in Openlayers, working in qgis. WMS working ok](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/267468/wfs-not-working-in-openlayers-working-in-qgis-wms-working-ok) and [Openlayers 4 WFS & vector select](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/285232/openlayers-4-wfs-vector-select)

**Edit**
Your both attempts do not work because it seems your are consuming data in EPSG:4326 whereas your map seems to use EPSG:3857. The different recipes you use do not make automatic reprojection of coordinates. Usually to sort out this kind of issue, I check coordinates by doing something like

```
vector.getSource().getFeatures()[0].getGeometry().getCoordinates()
```

I've made [a working example](https://bl.ocks.org/ThomasG77/5579a8831db6fa0f5641474e56739201) with your WFS Collection using a loader (like for [Openlayers 4 WFS & vector select](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/285232/openlayers-4-wfs-vector-select)). I've made some comments to explain a bit more below

```js
  var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    url: 'wfs.xml',
    format: new ol.format.WFS(),
    loader: function(extent, resolution, projection) {
     var url = 'wfs.xml';
     fetch(url)
       .then(response => response.text())
       .then(text => {
         // Add Features
         vectorSource.addFeatures(
           // Read WFS collection and do a reprojection of coordinates
           // from EPSG 4326 to EPSG 3857
           vectorSource.getFormat().readFeatures(text, {
             dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
             featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
           })
         );
       })
    }
  })
  var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource
  });

  map.addLayer(vector);
  // Event on the source to wait that WFS collection is completely loaded before zooming on extent of data
  vectorSource.on('change', e => {
    if (vectorSource.getState() === 'ready') {
      // vectorSource.getExtent() get a rectangle of extent
      // map.getView().fit take an extent an zoom on it
      map.getView().fit(vectorSource.getExtent());
    }
  })
```

Comment: Still didn't work as expected. I have edited my answer to explain the steps and results. Can you please take a look? Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! The code you gave works well. I had to convert it back to the old syntax though, don't know why it wouldn't work with the `=>` syntax. Anyway, can you please explain what exactly is happening within the loader of the code (`dataProjection` and `featurePorjection`) and in `vectorSource.on('change' ... `? Sorry if this is trivial but I'm new to both javascript and GIS.

Comment: Made some additions in my answer